# Mouse stops responding randomly

Tags: mouse, hardware

My PC's mouse stops responding randomly on Ubuntu 14.04. It starts working when I physically replug it or restart the PC. I formatted and reinstalled Ubuntu, but the issue persists. My mouse is not faulty since it works perfectly in Windows 8 on the same machine.

Comment: is it a wireless mouse?

Comment: no its a wired pc mouse.

Answer (score 0):

My Machine is an Advent Quantum Q200

I went into the bios by turning machine on and pressing delete.

I went into advanced settings and disabled the Bit Compatibility.

I saved and exited the bios settings rebooting back into Ubuntu.

This seems to have cured it for me.