# Mouse suspends randomly

Tags: usb, 15.04, mouse, lenovo

It happens that my mouse kind of suspends sometimes if I use the keyboard or the touchpad. It doesn't react to movement then but waits until a click is done. Unfortunately this happens rather random so it's difficult to check if some solution works.

Often the problem can be "solved" by unplugging the mouse shortly.
The problem seems to be similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse) but other then there powernap is not installed.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487425/mouse-stops-responding-randomly) a similar problem was solved by changing the Bit Compatibility in the bios. In my bios I could not find a similar point, what would it do anyway?

Is there a tool which gives me more information about my usb devices so I can check next time the error occurs?

The problem occurs on a lenovo Flex 2 under ubuntu 15.04 kernel 3.19. The problem wasn't there with 14.04, but then I got trouble with the touchpad.